# Audio Problems on 14.04

Tags: sound

My `Thinkpad T440p` is having audio problems with Ubuntu 14.04, and I don't have any idea where to start troubleshooting- I don't even recall there being a point where something seemed to have went wrong.

I just opened up my computer, and the audio wasn't working. After that, there was a very low frequency hum, and now there is a sound that is akin to fan noise. (It still is the speakers - if I hit the mute button it goes away).

How can I try to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

#### step1:

First open the  speech-dispatcher file :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Search for key RUN. If RUN=no then skip step1 to step2 , if RUN=yes then

```
change RUN=yes to RUN=no
```

Now reboot and try again.

#### step2:

In your terminal run the command

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

After the command ends(takes some time) then reboot and check your sound.

#### step3:

If you still facing sound problem try reinstalling Alsa and Pulse audio

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And force reload Alsa again:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

wait to finish and then restart

Comment: After 'step 2' my computer, which had no sound before returned to make a very low thrumming- after 'step 3' it now makes a static noise, that sounds like the fan working to hard. Should I conclude something is wrong with my speakers?